# Insufficient Content on Adsense activation on Angular website that required authentication

Tags: angular, adsense

Recently my AdSense request was rejected because it had 'insufficient content'. See [this](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/81904?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=1391540). My webpage is an Angular so there isn't much static html content. This is it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Timesheet</title>
  <base href="/">

  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>
    Loading...

  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Also my website requires authentication (Google Login). So only a simple login page will be accessible without authentication. How can I get my Adsense request approved?

Comment: You'd want/need server side rendering. AdSense is based off content, and if it is client rendered content then AdSense won't be useful: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/Aei-1VrBguU

Answer (score 2):

The best approach for you is using [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/). And implementing server-side rendering on your side. That's mean that when Google inspect your site it will see a normal link and content.

Another way is no so good but more simple for you. You can try to place the static HTML content inside the index.html and then inside the  tag. The contents will get replaced anyways once angular is fully loaded. But it will make the initial HTML response with a lot of text.

Answer (score 0):

Google's ability to read Javascript pages has improved over time so there is a good chance that Google CAN actually read your page but because you are forcing the user to log in before seeing your content Google is not able to see anything useful on your page. I'm afraid the only real way I know about to fix this issue is by having publicly available content.

Keep in mind that Google Adsense's ToS only allows you to put advertisements on Content pages, putting it on Login pages and the like is against their ToS. Make sure to read their Terms of Service:
https://www.google.com/adsense/new/localized-terms

That doesn't mean that Google doesn't appreciate static pages though and they will help Google crawl the website better, possibly resulting in better conversion rates.